# Is this a bug? No stunner yet I've got free equipments

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

First, let me create a scenario.

I've got a soldier (no specific soldier) with psychic ability `mind control`. he is facing two enemies, namely a muton and a sectopod. I've used `mind control` on the muton and succeded. I ended the round and as usual, the muton is flanked by the sectopod and killed the muton. I've killed the sectopod and the round finishes, thus winning it. At the rewards I've received a `plasma rifle`, `plasma pistol`, and a `alien grenade` along with the 6 weapon fragments (yup, I've calculated it).

So, is this a bug? Take note that I didn't even bring an arc thrower in this mission because I've interrogated every alien at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an enemy is killed while under mind control, you get their equipment.

Whether this is a bug or by design, we don't know, but it is consistent. Maybe the idea is that the MCed muton calmly laid down its arms before standing up in front of the sectopod? :-)

Comment: haha! i like this answer! although i've calculated the wep frags and the +6(plasma rifle,pistol and grenade) is still included in the reward screen. have you also experienced this bug/trick in getting free weapons w/ MCed enemies?

Comment: @ken hmm, I don't know. I don't think you should get the weapons *and* the fragments, and if you've counted right that definitely sounds like a bug. Also, I wasn't aware that mutons carried pistols - is there anything else that could have yielded the pistol during the mission?

Comment: In-story, the weapons selfdestruct when their owner dies. Which is why you can only get weapons by stunning, not killing. This is presumably the same sort of bug like the one where the death of a mind controlled alien could cause panic in your squaddies.